Approval comment mandatory for every step
We have implemented an apex class to enforce mandatory comments in the Opportunity approval process. The validation ensures that approvers cannot approve or reject an Opportunity without adding a comment. However, we are encountering inconsistent behaviour in the approval process:
Actual Behavior:
The first approver is able to approve the Opportunity without adding a comment.
When the approval moves to the second approver, they are unable to approve the Opportunity even if they add a comment and an error is displayed.
public with sharing class TA_Opportunity_CommentMandatory implements TriggerAction.BeforeUpdate {
    public void beforeUpdate(List<Opportunity> newList, List<Opportunity> oldList){
        validateCommentForApprovedOrRejected(newList, oldList);
    }
 
     public static void validateCommentForApprovedOrRejected(List<Opportunity> newList, List<Opportunity> oldList) {
        Map<Id, Opportunity> oldOppMap = new Map<Id, Opportunity>();
        for (Opportunity oldOpp : oldList) {
            oldOppMap.put(oldOpp.Id, oldOpp);
        }
 
        Set<Id> oppIds = new Set<Id>();
        for (Opportunity opp : newList) {
            Opportunity oldOpp = oldOppMap.get(opp.Id);
            if ((opp.Approval_Status__c == 'Approved' || opp.Approval_Status__c == 'Rejected') &&
                oldOpp.Approval_Status__c != opp.Approval_Status__c) {
                oppIds.add(opp.Id);
            }
        }
 
        if (oppIds.isEmpty()) { 
              return;
        } 
        List<ProcessInstance> processInstances = [
            SELECT Id, TargetObjectId
            FROM ProcessInstance
            WHERE TargetObjectId IN :oppIds
        ];
        Map<Id, Id> oppToProcessInstanceMap = new Map<Id, Id>();
        for (ProcessInstance pi : processInstances) {
            oppToProcessInstanceMap.put(pi.TargetObjectId, pi.Id);
        }
        List<ProcessInstanceStep> processSteps = [
            SELECT Id, ProcessInstanceId, StepStatus, Comments
            FROM ProcessInstanceStep
            WHERE ProcessInstanceId IN :oppToProcessInstanceMap.values()
              AND StepStatus IN ('Approved', 'Rejected')
        ];
        Map<Id, Boolean> processInstanceCommentMap = new Map<Id, Boolean>();
        for (ProcessInstanceStep step : processSteps) {
            if (!processInstanceCommentMap.containsKey(step.ProcessInstanceId)) {
                processInstanceCommentMap.put(step.ProcessInstanceId, !String.isBlank(step.Comments));
            }
        }
 
        for (Opportunity opp : newList) {
            Id processInstanceId = oppToProcessInstanceMap.get(opp.Id);
            if (processInstanceId != null && 
                (!processInstanceCommentMap.containsKey(processInstanceId) || !processInstanceCommentMap.get(processInstanceId))) {
                opp.addError('Comment is Mandatory.');
            }
        }
    }
}


Do you have checked this? - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1751/making-approval-comment-mandatory

https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdmvmUAB/checkbox-for-approval-comment-optional-mandatory


Yes ,it doesnt work for every step in approval process

without seeing the configured approval step actions it is hard to answer this.  Basically, the linked answer/blog post relies on Order of Execution tricks to ensure the Opportunity is updated and the ProcessInstanceStep is available for query.  I would look at your debug log carefully to ensure your code executes at the right time (and not too soon)
